# angular material selector's ListBox

Tags: angular-material, mat-select

I want to style only mat-select's ListBox width (the box that appears after the selector is opened).
Do you know how to do it?

I tried styling the width of mat select, but is allsow styles listBox's width?

```
<mat-form-field
  appearance="outline"
  [formGroup]="formGroup"
  [ngClass]="_field?.formFieldClass || ''"
>
  <mat-label *ngIf="_field?.label"> {{ _field.label }} </mat-label>
  <mat-select
    [formControlName]="_field.name"
    [placeholder]="_field?.placeholder || _field?.label || ''"
  >
    <mat-optgroup *ngIf="_field?.options?.length === 0">
      <div>No results found!</div>
    </mat-optgroup>
    <mat-option [hidden]="true"></mat-option>
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let item of _field?.options"
      [value]="item?.key || item.value"
    >
      {{ item.value }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <ng-container
    *ngFor="let validation of _field?.validations"
    ngProjectAs="mat-error"
  >
    <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get(_field.name)?.hasError(validation.name)">{{
      validation.message
    }}</mat-error>
  </ng-container>
</mat-form-field>
```

is there any way to style only listBox ?

Answer (score 0):

```
div[role="listbox"] {
   width: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**